# Почему при открытии страницы не заполняется стор SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, svelte

У меня есть код в `+page.ts`, который проверяет есть ли текущий пользователь. Если его нет, то происходит редирект на страницу с регистрацией:

```js
export function load() {
    const currentUser = get(user);
    if (!currentUser) {
        throw redirect(307, '/signin');
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит стор с пользователем в `stores.ts`:

```js
function getUserValue() {
    const userCookie = Cookies.get('session_token');
    return userCookie !== undefined ? jwtDecode(userCookie) : undefined;
}

export const user = writable(getUserValue());
```

Почему при открытии страницы сначала происходит редирект на регистрацию? Но если потом заново открыть эту же страницу без перезагрузки сайта, то значение в сторе с пользователем появляется и редирект не происходит? Разве стор с пользователем инициализируется не раньше чем редирект?

Прошелся дебаггером и почему-то при первом открытии страницы `Cookies.get('session_token')` - `undefined`, а при втором значение уже нормальное.